# Deposit tokens to pool -> transaction reverted by the EVM

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I`m trying to deposit funds from my wallet into a pool using the following Node.JS code.

```
require('dotenv').config()
const Web3 = require('web3')

//WEB3 Config
const web3 = new Web3(process.env.RPC_URL)
const wallet = web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY)

//SMART CONTRACT ABIs
const PEAR_POOL_ABI = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract PearToken","name":"_pear","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_startBlock","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_pearPerBlock","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_pearLockerAddress","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"CharityAddressUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"previousAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint16","name":"newAmount","type":"uint16"}],"name":"CharityFeeRateUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"pid","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"DevAddressUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"pid","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"EmergencyWithdraw","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"caller","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"previousAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"newAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"EmissionRateUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"FeeAddressUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"previousAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"newAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"LockerRateUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"LotteryAddressUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"previousAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint16","name":"newAmount","type":"uint16"}],"name":"LotteryMintRateUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"contract ILocker","name":"newAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"PearLockerUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"contract IReferral","name":"newAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"PearReferralUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"referrer","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"newAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ReferralCommissionPaid","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"previousAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"newAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ReferralRateUpdated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"pid","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"newAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RewardLockedUp","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"pid","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Withdraw","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BONUS_MULTIPLIER","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BURN_ADDRESS","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MAXIMUM_DEPOSIT_FEE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MAXIMUM_HARVEST_INTERVAL","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MAXIMUM_WITHDRAWAL_FEE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MAXIMUM_WITHDRAWFEE_INTERVAL","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_allocPoint","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"contract IBEP20","name":"_lpToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"_depositFeeBP","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_harvestInterval","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_withdrawalFeeInterval","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_withdrawalFeeBP","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"_withUpdate","type":"bool"}],"name":"add","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_pid","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"canHarvest","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"charityAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"charityFeeBP","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"","type":"uint16"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_pid","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_referrer","type":"address"}],"name":"deposit","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"devAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_pid","type":"uint256"}],"name":"emergencyWithdraw","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"feeAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_from","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_to","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getMultiplier","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"lockerRate","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"","type":"uint16"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"lotteryAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"lotteryMintRate","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"","type":"uint16"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"massUpdatePools","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_pid","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"noWithdrawFee","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pear","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract PearToken","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pearLockerAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pearPerBlock","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pearReferral","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract IReferral","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_pid","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"pendingPear","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract IBEP20","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"poolExistence","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"poolInfo","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract IBEP20","name":"lpToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"allocPoint","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"lastRewardBlock","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"accPearPerShare","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"depositFeeBP","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"harvestInterval","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"withdrawalFeeInterval","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"withdrawalFeeBP","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"poolLength","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"referralCommissionRate","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"","type":"uint16"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_pid","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_allocPoint","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"_depositFeeBP","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_harvestInterval","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_withdrawalFeeInterval","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_withdrawalFeeBP","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"_withUpdate","type":"bool"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_charityAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setCharityAddress","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"_charityFeeBP","type":"uint16"}],"name":"setCharityFeeRate","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_devAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setDevAddress","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeAddress","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"_lockerRate","type":"uint16"}],"name":"setLockerRate","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_lotteryAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setLotteryAddress","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"_lotteryMintRate","type":"uint16"}],"name":"setLotteryMintRate","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ILocker","name":"_pearLocker","type":"address"}],"name":"setPearLocker","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract IReferral","name":"_pearReferral","type":"address"}],"name":"setPearReferral","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"_referralCommissionRate","type":"uint16"}],"name":"setReferralCommissionRate","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"startBlock","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalAllocPoint","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalLockedUpRewards","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_pearPerBlock","type":"uint256"}],"name":"updateEmissionRate","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_pid","type":"uint256"}],"name":"updatePool","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"userInfo","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardDebt","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardLockedUp","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nextHarvestUntil","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"noWithdrawalFeeAfter","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_pid","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]


//SMART CONTRACT ADDRESSSES
const PEAR_POOL_CONTRACT="0xb12fefc21b12df492609942172412d4b75cbc709"


//smart contract objects
const pearPoolContract = new web3.eth.Contract(PEAR_POOL_ABI, PEAR_POOL_CONTRACT)


let tokenAddress = "0xc8bcb58caef1be972c0b638b1dd8b0748fdc8a44";
let walletAddress = "sadasdasdsad";

// The minimum ABI to get ERC20 Token balance
let minABI = [
  // balanceOf
  {
    "constant":true,
    "inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],
    "name":"balanceOf",
    "outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],
    "type":"function"
  },
  // decimals
  {
    "constant":true,
    "inputs":[],
    "name":"decimals",
    "outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],
    "type":"function"
  }
];

let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI,tokenAddress);

//Get PEAR balance
async function getBalance() {
const balanceBN = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call();
const decimalsBN = await contract.methods.decimals().call();

return balanceBN 
}




async function compound(amountPear){
    console.log('begin compounding')
    try{
        
        const gasLimit = 200000 //(await web3.eth.getBlock('latest')).gasLimit
        const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice()
        const txCost = web3.utils.fromWei(gasPrice.toString(),'ether') * gasLimit
        const pid = 2
        const address = "0x548D114B60A65886cef36872A494750c67A8bE43"
        const depositTx = await pearPoolContract.methods.deposit(pid,amountPear,address).send(
            {
            from: wallet.address,
            gas: gasLimit,
            gasPrice: gasPrice
            }
        )
        console.log(`deposit status: ${depositTx.status}`)
    } catch (err){
        currently_compounding = false
        console.log(`Deposit PEAR error ${err.message}`)
        return
    }
}

getBalance().then(function (result) {

compound(result)
/*
      const gasLimit = 200000
      const gasPrice = web3.eth.getGasPrice()
      const txCost = web3.utils.fromWei(gasPrice.toString(),'ether') * gasLimit
      const depositTx = dinoExtinctionContract.methods.transact(result).send(
            {
            from: wallet.address,
            gas: gasLimit,
            gasPrice: gasPrice
            }
        )
        console.log(`deposit status: ${depositTx.status}`);
        */
        
        console.log(`fetch amountPear ${result}`)
});
```

However, the transaction gets reverted.

```
Deposit PEAR error Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x6ede6427a0f6352a532dce6e276abb6af76520fb07c758670615860beaa25572",
  "blockNumber": 18894661,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 6468412,
  "effectiveGasPrice": "0xe7906543",
  "from": "sadasdasdsa",
  "gasUsed": 200000,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000001000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000004000000000000000000000200000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000040000004000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0xb12fefc21b12df492609942172412d4b75cbc709",
  "transactionHash": "0xc842386de44e5ca7e77938a189f56ac572f0edc0dbafaf68c08d4479133ffa2b",
  "transactionIndex": 33,
  "type": "0x0",
  "events": {
    "0": {
      "address": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010",
      "blockNumber": 18894661,
      "transactionHash": "0xc842386de44e5ca7e77938a189f56ac572f0edc0dbafaf68c08d4479133ffa2b",
      "transactionIndex": 33,
      "blockHash": "0x6ede6427a0f6352a532dce6e276abb6af76520fb07c758670615860beaa25572",
      "logIndex": 233,
      "removed": false,
      "id": "log_b1f76018",
      "returnValues": {},
      "signature": null,
      "raw": {
        "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c2ad6906b7c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005cf2b9ae1e549bee0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000910396755a3512ccf50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005ceff700b54de42e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000091039938079e1984b5",
        "topics": [
          "0x4dfe1bbbcf077ddc3e01291eea2d5c70c2b422b415d95645b9adcfd678cb1d63",
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010",
          "0x000000000000000000000000a4afcc90767e6f5f735ac66e56a85ebdbec75d94",
          "0x0000000000000000000000009c56f33b968f83922bccf6d7689b9c883af9de49"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I compared the transaction to the ones I executed on the website and the data looks the same.
My gutfeeling says that I need to convert the values I`m passing to the compound function, however I`m not sure as to where this should be converted (if at all)

Any pointers?

Comment: Successful transaction uses more than 215k gas, reverted transaction has gas limit set to 200k gas. I'd try with more than 200k gas.

Comment: Amazing, that was the issue indeed. Thanks!